# voximplant integration into existing app: user management & client login

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, voximplant

I'm evaluating [VoxImplant](https://voximplant.com/) for embedding video chat into my react native application.

I'm using [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/amplify/) and so [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) as the identity provider.

I think I'll need to automatically create VoxImplant users on Cognito SignUp (i.e. in a lambda function triggered by a postConfirmation event).

But how can I login users to VoxImplant when the app will start?

I think [one time keys](https://voximplant.com/docs/guides/sdk/onetimekey) could be a way to go, but I do not understand how to use them.
Maybe I have to store the password I used when creating the VoxImplant user in my backend and use it when calculating the token (on backend side) to return to the VoxImplant client?

Moreover, in the example provided from the documentation, it looks like the client is sending appUser and appUserPassword to the backend in order to calculate the token. This confuses me too, because I do not understand where this data comes from. This is not the user password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one time keys seem to be the solution for your case. You need to store password (or md5(username+':voximplant.com:'+password) for more security) in your backend and use it to calculate the token to send to the client.

The client doesn't transmit password to backend. The authentication flow is the following:

1. SDK obtains one time key from Voximplant (e.g. https://voximplant.com/docs/references/androidsdk/client/iclient#requestonetimekey for Android)
2. Application passes that key to your backend.
3. Backend retrieves corresponding voximplant user login and password (or hashed password) from it's internal storage and calculates the token using that data and one time key
4. Application receives token from backend and passes it to Voximplant SDK to complete authentication (e.g. https://voximplant.com/docs/references/androidsdk/client/iclient#loginwithonetimekey for Android)
5. Voximplant verifies token and authenticates the SDK